# sizingDrp inner content is not showing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In the below HTML it is not showing inner content when click the + drop down button as it supposed to

```html
<div style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Chronicle-Display-Roman'; font-size: 16px;">For all sizing information please click on the links below:</div>
<p> </p>
<div class="sizingAcc" style="max-width: 910px; margin: auto; font-family: 'Century Gothic'; margin-bottom: 20px;">
<div class="sizingBtn toggle">Information <span class="plusSign">+</span></div>
<div class="sizingDrp inner">
<div><strong></strong></div>
<div><strong>*Please note that this guide is for reference only. </strong></div>
<div><br />We wish to create a stress-free shopping experience for your formal &amp; prom dress needs, which is why we have measured each individual garment in-house.</div>
<div>of each different fabric &amp; how it will fit your body.<br /><br />If you are in between sizes or not sure which size to purchase we understand, and are more than happy to assist you. </div>
<div><br /><b>Contact Us:</b></div>
<div>Talk to one of our stylists via or Live Chat below.</div>
<div>Providing us with your usual dress size and measurements (Bust, Waist &amp; Hips) can improve our sizing recommendations for you. <br /><br /><strong>Want to see more images of our gowns?</strong></div>
<div>Visit<span style="color: #b49d73;"> </span>on Instagram and see our gowns on real customers.<br /><br /></div>
</div>
<div class="sizingBtn toggle">How to Measure <span class="plusSign">+</span></div>
<div class="sizingDrp inner"><img src="" alt="How to measure" /></div>
<div class="sizingBtn toggle">Ready to Wear Size Chart <span class="plusSign">+</span></div>
<div class="sizingDrp inner"><img src="" alt="Ready to Wear Size Chart" /></div>
<div class="sizingBtn toggle">Beaded Couture Size Chart <span class="plusSign">+</span></div>
<div class="sizingDrp inner"><img src="" alt="Beaded Couture size chart" /></div>
<div class="sizingBtn toggle">Made to Order Size Chart <span class="plusSign">+</span></div>
<div class="sizingDrp inner"><img src="" alt="Made to Order Size Chart" /></div>
<div class="sizingBtn toggle">Shoes Size Chart <span class="plusSign">+</span></div>
<div class="sizingDrp inner"><img src="" alt="Shoes Size Chart" /></div>
<div class="sizingBtn toggle">Made to Order Fabric Guide <span class="plusSign">+</span></div>
<div class="sizingDrp inner"><img src="" alt="Made to Order Fabric Guide" /></div>
<div class="sizingBtn toggle">Our Models <span class="plusSign">+</span></div>
<div class="sizingDrp inner"><img src="" alt="" width="300" height="200" /></div>
</div>

<style>
.sizingAcc .sizingBtn{
        font-family: 'Chronicle-Display-Roman';
        font-size: 16px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }

    
    .sizingDrp{
        display: none;
    }
   
    .show{
    display: block;
    }

    
    
    div.sizingBtn.toggle {
        padding: 20px 5px;
        margin: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
    }
    span.plusSign {
        float: right;
    }
    .sizingDrp.inner.show {
        border-top: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

I have tried to add the below code but then it's showing all the inner content before clicking the drop down + button

```
  .sizingDrp.inner.show
{
    display: block;
}
```

Any suggestions how to make this code work to display the inner content? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks heaps!

**Edit:**

I have added the below JS code but it is not working

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sizingBtn.toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.sizingDrp.inner').toggleClass('show');
    $(this).find('.plusSign').text(function(_, text) {
      return text === '+' ? '-' : '+';
    });
  });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Where is your click event listener or handler? I don't see any `onclick` or any other Javascript in your code.

Comment: Hi @Geshode I have updated my question with the new js script. Can you have a look now please?

Comment: And from where do you call the `toggleContent` function? I don't see it being called anywhere in the provided code.

Comment: Hi @Geshode I have updated my Js code and I don't think I have to call it anywhere?

Comment: The updated version doesn't have to be called from anywhere. And if you have `display: block;` inside the `show` class's css, it also works. So, you problem is solved, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add click event listeners to each element with the class `"sizingBtn"`, which toggles a class to display the content.

For example:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.sizingBtn').forEach(el => 
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const content = el.nextElementSibling;
    content.classList.toggle('show');
  })
);
```

```css
.sizingAcc .sizingBtn{font-family:Chronicle-Display-Roman;font-size:16px;letter-spacing:1px}.sizingDrp{display:none}div.sizingBtn.toggle{padding:20px 5px;margin:0;border-top:1px solid #dedede}span.plusSign{float:right}.sizingDrp.inner.show{border-top:none!important}
.sizingDrp.inner.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Chronicle-Display-Roman'; font-size: 16px;">For all sizing information please click on the links below:</div>
<p> </p>
<div class="sizingAcc" style="max-width: 910px; margin: auto; font-family: 'Century Gothic'; margin-bottom: 20px;">
<div class="sizingBtn toggle">Information <span class="plusSign">+</span></div>
<div class="sizingDrp inner">
<div><strong></strong></div>
<div><strong>*Please note that this guide is for reference only. </strong></div>
<div><br />We wish to create a stress-free shopping experience for your formal &amp; prom dress needs, which is why we have measured each individual garment in-house.</div>
<div>of each different fabric &amp; how it will fit your body.<br /><br />If you are in between sizes or not sure which size to purchase we understand, and are more than happy to assist you. </div>
<div><br /><b>Contact Us:</b></div>
<div>Talk to one of our stylists via or Live Chat below.</div>
<div>Providing us with your usual dress size and measurements (Bust, Waist &amp; Hips) can improve our sizing recommendations for you. <br /><br /><strong>Want to see more images of our gowns?</strong></div>
<div>Visit<span style="color: #b49d73;"> </span>on Instagram and see our gowns on real customers.<br /><br /></div>
</div>
<div class="sizingBtn toggle">How to Measure <span class="plusSign">+</span></div>
<div class="sizingDrp inner"><img src="" alt="How to measure" /></div>
<div class="sizingBtn toggle">Ready to Wear Size Chart <span class="plusSign">+</span></div>
<div class="sizingDrp inner"><img src="" alt="Ready to Wear Size Chart" /></div>
<div class="sizingBtn toggle">Beaded Couture Size Chart <span class="plusSign">+</span></div>
<div class="sizingDrp inner"><img src="" alt="Beaded Couture size chart" /></div>
<div class="sizingBtn toggle">Made to Order Size Chart <span class="plusSign">+</span></div>
<div class="sizingDrp inner"><img src="" alt="Made to Order Size Chart" /></div>
<div class="sizingBtn toggle">Shoes Size Chart <span class="plusSign">+</span></div>
<div class="sizingDrp inner"><img src="" alt="Shoes Size Chart" /></div>
<div class="sizingBtn toggle">Made to Order Fabric Guide <span class="plusSign">+</span></div>
<div class="sizingDrp inner"><img src="" alt="Made to Order Fabric Guide" /></div>
<div class="sizingBtn toggle">Our Models <span class="plusSign">+</span></div>
<div class="sizingDrp inner"><img src="" alt="" width="300" height="200" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Shopify-Developer Updated the example in my answer.

Comment: You are a living legend @Unmitigated. Thanks so so much man! God bless you! :)